# Travis Builds are failing with PyOpenSSL with urllib.requests.urlopen

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, travis-ci, urllib3

So recently my build system started failing and the only delta between the previous working build and the new one is a "Code of Conduct" markdown file which generally doesn't impact the code.

My test system is built on TravisCI and the current error I received is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/conda/envs/tenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/travis/build/Sulstice/cocktail-shaker/tests/test_file_handler.py", line 47, in test_file_production
    FileWriter("tests/test", modified_molecules, "cdxml")
  File "/home/travis/build/Sulstice/cocktail-shaker/cocktail_shaker/file_handler.py", line 60, in __init__
    method_to_call(self)
  File "/home/travis/build/Sulstice/cocktail-shaker/cocktail_shaker/file_handler.py", line 129, in cactus_writer
    response = request.get()
  File "/home/travis/build/Sulstice/cocktail-shaker/cocktail_shaker/request_handler.py", line 51, in get
    request = urlopen(self.url)
  File "/home/travis/conda/envs/tenv/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/travis/conda/envs/tenv/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/travis/conda/envs/tenv/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/travis/conda/envs/tenv/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/travis/conda/envs/tenv/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/home/travis/conda/envs/tenv/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
```

Not every time it gives me this specific stack trace. It varies with:

```
urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

So I decided to test this locally and low and behold I receive that exact error. Eventually I landed on a handshake exception clause that made me think this is a TLS issue. So I pip installed PyOpenSSL and it all worked (locally)!

I figured I would be able to just add pyopenssl into the requirements.txt and and run my travis build again but then I am back to the same error. So now I am stumped.

Here is my .travis file:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"

# switch to new infrastructure
sudo: false

before_install:
# download and install miniconda
- wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.1.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
- bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/conda
- export PATH="$HOME/conda/bin:$PATH"
- hash -r
- conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
- conda update -q conda
# Useful for debugging any issues with conda
- conda info -a

# create and activate the build/test environment
- conda create -q -n tenv python=$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION pip cmake
- source activate tenv

# additional .debs we need:
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - build-essential
    - openjdk-8-jdk
    - swig
    - libjpeg-dev

install:

# install the most recent rdkit package from the RDKit anaconda channel.
- conda install -q -c rdkit rdkit

- python setup.py install
- pip install python-coveralls
- pip install coveralls
- pip install coverage       # Add me to install coverage.py
- pip install nose           # Add me to install nose

before_script:
# RDKit
- export RDBASE=$CONDA_PREFIX/Library/share/RDKit
- echo $RDBASE

script:
- python -m nose --verbose --with-coverage

after_success:
- python -m coveralls
```

and here is an example request:

```
url = https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/tautomers%3ANC%28Br%29C%28%3DO%29NCC%28%3DO%29O/file/xml/\?format\=mol2\&get3d\=True

   from urllib.request import urlopen

   try:
      request = urlopen(url)
   except Exception as e:
      print (e)
```

Comment: The website you're requesting does not appear to be fast or reliable. I would suggest using urllib3 instead of `urllib` in order to configure retries. But the best option would be to avoid requesting external web site from Travis, this is the best way to get flaky tests. (Also, why tag your questions with `python-requests` and `urllib3` when you're not using those libraries?)

Comment: @QuentinPradet I can remove this segment of the code and I tagged it to see if there were alternate routes using that library that might produce a more stable test if someone had that knowledge.